# GWT - how can I make the buttons equally take up a panel (programmatically)?

Tags: gwt

I have a `HorizontalPanel` and I added two `Button`s to it. 
The `HorizontalPanel` is already as wide as its parent.
I want each `Button` to take a half of the `HorizontalPanel`. How can I do it programmatically?
Or maybe am I using the wrong panel? Any advice would be appreciated.

I tried `setWidth("50%")`. It looks strange. I also tried other panels e.g. `FlowPanel`. I just cannot figure it out...

Comment: What do you mean by "looks strange"?

Comment: Look at [GWT Layout](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use `setWidth("100%")` instead of `setWidth("50%")` for both the Buttons and then add it to HorizontalPanel.

Comment: It should be `setWidth("100%")` for `HorizontalPanel` also otherwise it will not work.